# Flutter Application code doesn't run on emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

The code does not run in androidstudio emulator. Endlessly Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode... [image]
When logging in it used to show a warning that it doesn't see Dart'a and Flutter'a sdk, I think I fixed it[image]

Completely reinstalled FLutter and Dart, thought it would help

Comment: Try `flutter run --verbose` in terminal to see what's happening.

Comment: Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
           This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

Can u help me how i can fix this?

Comment: `cd` into your project folder.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you, can you explain please..............?

Comment: `cd` is command-line shell command short for change directory. For example `cd myName/desktop/projects/my_flutter_app` or open your project directory in vs code from File>Open Folder then go to terminal and run `flutter run --verbose` again.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
I did, and it came up